# How can we keep the font scaling up and down but make it not so context sensitive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, scalability

Deep into a project we are having problems with the use of em's in our font-size.
We have several markup **modules that we are reusing in different contexts**.
Constant head aches with the calculated font-size being different in the different contexts.
Using em's are important to us as we are using a responsive design. So scalability of the font-size is a must have. Please see jsFiddle for a simple example.
**How can we keep the font scaling up and down but make it not so context sensitive?**

Comment: Part of your problem is the use of the *magic* 62.5% font-size on the body element to make math easier is causing all sorts of inheritance problems (see:  http://csswizardry.com/2011/05/font-sizing-with-rem-could-be-avoided/).

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance can be quite annoying, espcially when working with ems. As you know the context thanks to the class names you should be able to overcome this problem by applying some simple maths.

Let's take everything in `.context1` as the ideal, your CSS currently looks like:

```
.context1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.context2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.my-font-size {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

In your case, the first heading will be `3em`, the second will actually be `4.5em` because the parent is defined as being 1.5x bigger. To get around this, you could do the following:

```
.context1 {
    font-size: 1em;    //default font size for .context1
}
.context2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;  //default font size for .context2
}
.my-font-size {
    font-size: 3em;    //default font size for .my-font-size
}
.context2 .my-font-size {
    font-size: 2em;    //adjust the font size for the parent's value (3/1.5)
}
```

Similarly, you could define it so that `.context2` was the norm:

```
.context1 .my-font-size {
    font-size: 4.5em;    //(3 * 1.5)
}
```

[Here's the updated the example](http://codepen.io/cchana/pen/IFcCJ).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the rem unit.

http://jsfiddle.net/6YC89/1/

```
.context1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.context2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.my-font-size {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Browser support is fairly good (see:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem).  The only major browser that doesn't support it is IE8.